# VBA Shell Run Exit Code Capture and interpret

Tags: vba, shell, batch-file

In my log file, I want to capture exit code and the meaning of the code.
Is there a reference to this?

```vb
ReturnCode = Shell(ThisWorkbook.Path + "\DELETE_A_FILE.bat")
```

My code (below) seems to work, but ruturns 14400.

I didn't know how to interpret the code.
I found this, but I don't understand, because my number (14400) is not in the list...
http://www.febooti.com/products/automation-workshop/online-help/events/run-dos-cmd-command/exit-codes/

Is there a reference to properly interpret different codes so that I know how to handle them in my code?

Are negative numbers errors and positive numbers successes?

THESE EDITS were applied based on comments to original question....:

MY Batch file is something like this:
rmdir /S /Q  c:\temp\abc.pdf

So what the commenter(s) below seem to be saying is that the return code depends on what is in the .bat file.   The .bat file can have multiple statements in it.  Is the return code based on the last statement in the bat file?

Comment: You can return anything you want. There may be conventions, but this is entirely implementation specific.

Comment: It's important to note that the script itself is capable of updating the exit code. Without seeing the contents of DELETE_A_FILE.bat, it's impossible to say for certain what that code means.

Comment: The .bat file can have multiple statements in it.  Is the return code based on the last statement in the bat file?  My bat file has something like this:  rmdir /S /Q "C:\temp\abc.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the batch file didn't come with some `readme.txt`, the reference would be the batch file itself.

If there are no comments explaining each exit code, then you'll have to infer their meaning from the script.